# How do I take a string and make festival say it

Tags: python, python-2.7, gnome-terminal, festival

How do I take a string such as: `K = "Hello User"` and use it in the code that says it using festival tts: `os.system('echo "Hello user." | festival --tts')`? Is there a way to do it some other way (1st way would be better)
I tried searching to do this on Google, Youtube and StackOverflow but I guess that there is very less info on festival tts. If anyone can help it would nice.
Thank you.
The complete code is:

```
import os        
K = "Hello user."        
os.system('echo "X" | festival --tts')
```

I want to enter the text from string K to the Marked 'X' in the last line.
Also I use linux-Terminal to run the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just be able to do something like this:

```
os.system('echo %s | festival --tts' % K)
```

That should replace the %s with the string K

Comment: Thank you very much it did the trick. I tried something similar but had added the  % after the parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

Use [str.format](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format).

```
import os        
K = "Hello user."        
os.system('echo "{0}" | festival --tts'.format(K))
```

Answer (score 0):

You always shoud use direct func call insead create a new process. Create new process or a series of process take a memory usage and additional loading CPU. When you developing system you should receive API from software provider:.

Let's I show you Festival python binding example:

```
import festival
festival.initialize(1, 210000)
festival.say("Hello World")
```

You may receive more detail on festival python binding GitHub project or on official Python PyPi server.

Answer (score -1):

Install *festival* by typing on your Ubuntu terminal

```
sudo apt install festival
```

and then:

```
echo 'heyyy'    | festival --tts
```